# SaltStack JSON Decoder Error after upgrading to 3006

Tags: json, salt-stack

We have the following saltstack code that works well with SaltStack 3004.2:

```
                            ---
                            [...]
                                {% elif network == 'sfe' %}
                                    [Link]
                                    MTUBytes={{ pillar['storage']['sfe_mtu'] }}
                                    [Network]
                                    DHCP=no
                                    Address={{ salt['address.client_get_address']('api', pillar['api']['user_password'], network, grains['host']) }}/{{ pillar['networking']['subnets'][network].split('/')[1] }}    <======================
                                {% elif network == 'sbe' %}
                                    [Link]
                                    MTUBytes={{ pillar['storage']['sbe_mtu'] }}
                                    [Network]
                                    DHCP=no
                            [...]
                            ---
```

However, in 3006.1, we get the following error for the line listed above "Address" and we cannot understand what is wrong with it.

Is there a change we need to make in the code to adjust for this new version or do we have a package depenndecy issue, or version issue? Any help would be appreciated.

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

For reference:

```
Salt Version:
          Salt: 3006.1

Python Version:
        Python: 3.10.11 (main, May  5 2023, 02:31:54) [GCC 11.2.0]

Dependency Versions:
          cffi: 1.14.6
      cherrypy: unknown
      dateutil: 2.8.1
     docker-py: 1.10.6
         gitdb: 4.0.10
     gitpython: 3.1.31
        Jinja2: 3.1.2
       libgit2: 1.6.4
  looseversion: 1.0.2
      M2Crypto: 0.38.0
          Mako: 1.2.4
       msgpack: 1.0.2
  msgpack-pure: Not Installed
  mysql-python: Not Installed
     packaging: 22.0
     pycparser: 2.21
      pycrypto: 3.18.0
  pycryptodome: 3.9.8
        pygit2: 1.12.1
  python-gnupg: 0.4.8
        PyYAML: 5.4.1
         PyZMQ: 23.2.0
        relenv: 0.12.3
         smmap: 5.0.0
       timelib: 0.2.4
       Tornado: 4.5.3
           ZMQ: 4.3.4

System Versions:
          dist: debian 10 buster
        locale: utf-8
       machine: x86_64
       release: 4.19.0-24-cloud-amd64
        system: Linux
       version: Debian GNU/Linux 10 buster
```

Answer (score 0):

Code was good, it seems that 3006 version of salt introduced `netapi_enable_clients` which led to permissions issue accessing the api.